# why am I getting segmentation fault on the code below?

Tags: c, fault

I have a txt file where I just want to get lines bigger than 12 characters. Than these lines are inserted in a variable called graph of type graph_node.

txt file:

```
1,"execCode(workStation,root)","OR",0
2,"RULE 4 (Trojan horse installation)","AND",0
3,"accessFile(workStation,write,'/usr/local/share')","OR",0
4,"RULE 16 (NFS semantics)","AND",0
5,"accessFile(fileServer,write,'/export')","OR",0
6,"RULE 10 (execCode implies file access)","AND",0
7,"canAccessFile(fileServer,root,write,'/export')","LEAF",1
6,7,-1
```

graph node type:

```
#ifndef Graph_Structure
#define Graph_Structure

struct Graph_Node{

    char id[50];
    char node_name[50];

    struct Graph_Node* next;
    struct Graph_Node* edges;

    };  

typedef struct Graph_Node graph_node;


#endif
```

this is the method to insert data into graph variable:

```
void insert_node(graph_node** node, graph_node* data){

    printf("\nINSERTING\n");

    graph_node* temp = (graph_node*)malloc(sizeof(graph_node));

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(data->id); i++)
        temp->id[i] = data->id[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(data->node_name) - 1; i++)
        temp->node_name[i] = data->node_name[i];

    temp -> next = *node;
    *node = temp;

    }
```

this is the method to get the lines in the txt file bigger than 12 characters:

```
void generate_nodes(graph_node** graph, char* file_name){

    graph_node* data = (graph_node*)malloc(sizeof(graph_node));

    FILE* f_Data_Pointer = fopen(file_name, "r");
    FILE* f_Aux_Pointer = fopen(file_name, "r");

    char c = 0; char line[256];

        int counter = 0; 
        int q = 0; //quotation marks

        bool jump_line = false;

    while(!feof(f_Data_Pointer)){

        c = 0; memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

        while(c != '\n' && !feof(f_Aux_Pointer)){ // check line

            c = fgetc(f_Aux_Pointer); 
            line[counter] = c;
            counter++;

        }

        if(strlen(line) > 12){ //lines with no edges  

         /*line[counter-3] != '-' && line[counter-2] != '1'*/

         int size = strlen(line); printf("\nline size: %d\n", size);

            counter = 0; c = 0;

            while(c != ','){ //id

                c = fgetc(f_Data_Pointer);

                if(c != ','){

                    data->id[counter] = c;          
                    counter++;
                }

                printf("%c", c);

            }


            counter = 0; c = 0;

            while(1){ //node_name

                c = fgetc(f_Data_Pointer);

                if(c != '"'){

                data->node_name[counter] = c;
                counter++;

                } 

                else{

                    q++;                
                }

                if(q > 1 && c == ',')
                    break;

                printf("%c", c);

            }

            counter = 0; c = 0; 

            while(c != '\n'){ 

                c = fgetc(f_Data_Pointer);
                printf("%c", c);

            }

            insert_node(graph, data);
            memset(data->id, 0, sizeof(data->id));
            memset(data->node_name, 0, sizeof(data->node_name));

        }

        else{ //lines with edges

            while(c != '\n' && !feof(f_Data_Pointer)){ 

                c = fgetc(f_Data_Pointer);

            }

        }

    }

    fclose(f_Data_Pointer);
    fclose(f_Aux_Pointer);

}
```

I am getting the errors inside the insert method on the commands "for" in "strlen" it says that data->id and data->node_name are not initialized but I don't understand why. I used malloc on data:

```
graph_node* data = (graph_node*)malloc(sizeof(graph_node));
```

error:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) ==3612== at 0x4C30B18: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:510) ==3612== by 0x4008B2: insert_node (mulval.c:44) ==3612== by 0x400C03: generate_nodes (mulval.c:159) ==3612== by 0x400CE8: main (mulval.c:187)
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. It would be more readable without the double line spacing, but with sensible whitespace.

Comment: In `insert_node` you are copying all characters expect the 0-terminating one. Use `strcpy`: `strcpy(tmp->id, data->id);`

Comment: have you heard about `strcpy`/`strncpy`? :)

Comment: also [why while(!foef(...)) is alway wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Always test the return value from `fopen`. Also `char c;` ==> `int c;` always read the man pages.

Comment: that is what I get guys running with valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3612==    at 0x4C30B18: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:510)
==3612==    by 0x4008B2: insert_node (mulval.c:44)
==3612==    by 0x400C03: generate_nodes (mulval.c:159)
==3612==    by 0x400CE8: main (mulval.c:187)

Comment: I ran valgrind with option "--track-origins=yes" and it says "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation" in the line I use malloc when I declare data

Comment: So, look out for uninitialised values. Note that local variables must be explicity initialised.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem in your code is that you are constantly ignoring the
`'\0'`-terminating byte and pass to functions like `strlen` which expects a
valid string (one that is 0-terminated).

For example in `insert_node`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(data->id); i++)
        temp->id[i] = data->id[i];
```

Here you are copying all characters expect the `'\0'`-terminating byte,
`temp->id` will store a sequence of characters but it is **not** a string.
`strlen(data->id)` will have an undefined behaviour because `data->id` is most
likely not 0-terminated if you initialized it without 0-terminating the string.

Here you should use `strcpy` if you know that the source strings is smaller than
49 characters long, or `strncpy` to be completely sure:

```
strncpy(temp->id, data->id, sizeof temp->id);
temp->id[sizeof(temp->id) - 1] = 0;
```

Same thing with `node_name`. Also you are not checking if `malloc` returned
`NULL`.

Also the `foef` lines are wrong, see [Why `while(!foef(...))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

You should rewrite this

```
while(c != '\n' && !feof(f_Aux_Pointer)){ // check line
    c = fgetc(f_Aux_Pointer); 
    line[counter] = c;
    counter++;
}
```

like this:

```
int c; // <-- not char c

while((c = fgetc(f_Aux_Pointer)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    line[counter++] = c;

line[counter] = 0;  // terminating the string!
```

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, it should be `int`, otherwise the
comparison with `EOF` will go wrong. And here you ignored to set the
0-terminating byte, the result was a sequence of characters, but not a string.
The next line `if(strlen(line) ...` overflow because of this, as `strlen` will
keep looking for the 0-terminating byte beyond the limits. For me is not clear
why you even check for `EOF`, as you would keep reading when the outer `while`
loop resumes. If `f_Aux_Pointer` got to the end, shouldn't the function just
return? I'm not really sure what you are doing there. Also there is no strategy
for when the newline is not in the first 49 read characters. I think you should
rethink your strategy here.

It also would have been easier to do:

```
if(fgets(line, sizeof line, f_Aux_Pointer) == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    return; // perhaps this?
}

line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // removing the newline

if(strlen(line) > 12)
...
```

Here

```
while(c != ','){ //id

    c = fgetc(f_Data_Pointer);

    if(c != ','){

        data->id[counter] = c;          
        counter++;
    }

    printf("%c", c);

}
```

you have same error as above, you never set the \0-terminating byte. At the end
of the `while` you should have `data->id[counter] = 0;`. The same thing in the
next `while` loop.

In `generate_nodes` you don't need to allocate memory for the temporal
`graph_node` object as `insert_node` will create a copy anyway. You can do:

```
graph_node data;

...
data.id[counter] = c;
...
data.node_name[counter] = c;
...

insert_node(graph, &data);
data.id[0] = 0;
data.node_name[0] = 0;
```

and you will have one `malloc` less to worry about.

---

**EDIT**

Because your IDs are always numerical, I'd change the struct to this:

```
struct Graph_Node{
    int id;
    char node_name[50];

    struct Graph_Node* next;
    struct Graph_Node* edges;
};
```

which would make life easier. If your conditions are true
that only the lines you need are longer than 12 characters and that the lines
you are interested are always of the same format (no spaces between the commas,
second column is always quotes) as the ones posted in your
answer, then you can parse it like this:

```
int generate_nodes(graph_node **graph, const char *file_name)
{
    if(file_name == NULL || graph == NULL)
        return 0; // return error

    // no need to allocate memory for it
    // if the insert_node is going to make a
    // copy anyway
    struct Graph_Node data = { .next = NULL, .edges = NULL };

    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n", file_name,
                strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }

    // no line will be longer than 1024
    // based on your conditions
    char line[1024];

    size_t linenmr = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        linenmr++;
        // getting rid of the newline
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;

        if(strlen(line) <= 12)
            continue; // resume reading, skipt the line

        char *sep;
        long int id = strtol(line, &sep, 0);

        // assuming that there is not white spaces
        // before and after the commas
        if(*sep != ',')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning, line %lu is malformatted, '<id>,' exepcted\n", linenmr);
            continue;
        }

        data.id = id;

        // format is: "....",

        if(sep[1] != '"')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning, line %lu is malformatted, \"<string>\", exepcted\n", linenmr);
            continue;
        }

        // looking for ",
        char *endname = strstr(sep + 2, "\","); 

        if(endname == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning, line %lu is malformatted, \"<string>\", exepcted\n", linenmr);
            continue;
        }

        // ending string at ",
        // easier to do strcnpy
        *endname = 0;

        strncpy(data.node_name, sep + 2, sizeof data.node_name);
        data.node_name[sizeof(data.node_name) - 1] = 0;

        insert_node(graph, &data);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

Now the interesting bits are these:

```
    char *sep;
    long int id = strtol(line, &sep, 0);

    // assuming that there is not white spaces
    // before and after the commas
    if(*sep != ',')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning, line %lu is malformatted, '<id>,' exepcted\n", linenmr);
        continue;
    }
```

[`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) is a function that converts a number in a string to an actual
integer. This function is better than `atoi`, because it allows you to convert
numbers in different bases, from binary to hexadecimal. The second advantage is
that it tells you where it stopped reading. This is great for error detection,
and I use this behviour to detect if the line has the correct format. If the
line has the correct format, a comma `,` must appear next to the number, I check
for this and if it's not true, I print an error message and skip the line and
continue reading the file.

The next `if` checks if the next character is a quote `"`, because based on your
file, the second argument is enclosed in quotes. Sadly the separtor of the
arguments is a comma which is also used as a normal character in the string.
This makes things a little bit more complex (you cannot use `strtok` here).
Once again, I assume that the whole
argument ends in `",`. Note that this does not take into consideration escaped
quotes. A line like this:

```
3,"somefunc(a,b,\"hello\",d)","OR",0
```

would be parsed incorrectly. When `",` is found, I set the quote to `'\0'` so
that it is more easier to use `strncpy`, otherwise I would have to calculate the
length of the string, check that it's length doesn't surpass the destination size, etc.
If you need to keep parsing, `endname + 1` should point to the next comma,
otherwise the format is wrong.

```
    strncpy(data.node_name, sep + 2, sizeof data.node_name);
    data.node_name[sizeof(data.node_name) - 1] = 0;
```

Here I copy the string. The source is `sep + 2`, because `sep` points to the
first comma, so you have to skip it. The next character is the quote, so you
have to skip it as well, hence `sep + 2`. Because the legth of the name is
unknown, it's better to use `strncpy`, this will ensure that you don't write more
bytes than you need.

The last step is to insert the node into the graph. Note that I didn't allocate
memory, because I know that `insert_node` is a going to make a new copy anyway.
Because the `data` is only used temporarily, you don't need to allocate memory,
just pass a pointer to `data` (by passing `&data`) to `insert_node`.

I've tested this function with a dummy `graph` and a dummy `insert_node` that
only prints the node:

```
void insert_node(graph_node** node, graph_node* data)
{
    printf("ID: %d, node_name: %s\n", data->id, data->node_name);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
ID: 1, node_name: execCode(workStation,root)
ID: 2, node_name: RULE 4 (Trojan horse installation)
ID: 3, node_name: accessFile(workStation,write,'/usr/local/share')
ID: 4, node_name: RULE 16 (NFS semantics)
ID: 5, node_name: accessFile(fileServer,write,'/export')
ID: 6, node_name: RULE 10 (execCode implies file access)
ID: 7, node_name: canAccessFile(fileServer,root,write,'/export')
```

Now if you use this code and you keep getting valgrind errors, then that means
that you still have errors in other parts of your code that you haven't shown
us.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The aux_pointer is to check first if the line is smaller than 12 characters because I don't want to add them to graph variable. And graph->node_name never gets newline charactere.

Comment: the last part I didn't understand. You mean change "graph_node* data = (graph_node*)malloc(sizeof(graph_node));" to "graph_node data;" so it is not a pointer anymore and than I dont need to use malloc?

Comment: I made the changes but I still get segmentation fault. The only change I didn't make was the last one because I didnt understand

Comment: *so it is not a pointer anymore and than I dont need to use malloc?* yes, that's correct. By not being a pointer, it's an object on the stack. ---- *but I still get segmentation fault* I still have trouble understanding your parsing of the data. Can you edit your question and show a few lines of the input file and explain what the lines means, which are the ones you want, which are not. At some point you look for a comma, I'm not sure if that's correct, I don't know your algorithm.

Comment: yes that is right I look for a comma, because I want the id before the first comma and than the name of the node after the first comma. But I don't want lines in which there are only numbers followed by commas

Comment: @user8955046 like I said edit you question and add a few lines of the input file and which lines you want to read and which you don't.

Comment: I made the edit. In the txt file as you can see above there is I just want lines like the first "1,"execCode(workStation,root)","OR",0" but in this line I just want "1,"execCode(workStation,root)"," they are the id and the name of the node.

Comment: The last line which is "6,7,-1" I don't want to get them and they are allways smaller than 12 characters

Comment: and `"1"` is the ID and `"execCode"` node_name? Are IDs always numeric?

Comment: yes that is correct! and IDs are allways numeric. But the node name would be: execCode(workStation,root)

Comment: @user8955046 I've made an update of my answer addressing your last comments.

Comment: thank you for the changes! it is almost working the only problem is that it's returning only the first three letters of node name. I mean for example: execCode(workStation,root) just returns exe

Comment: @Pablo I am having problems in generating the edges in my graph now according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832974/why-my-c-code-to-generate-a-graph-from-a-txt-file-is-not-working

Comment: @user8955046 I'll take a look at this later.

Comment: @Pablo now is only missing the edges from the graph in this question the nodes were dealt