# Why my c code to generate a graph from a txt file is not working?

Tags: c, graph

I'm having many difficulties with c language. I'm currently trying to generate a graph from a txt file according to this question: [why am I getting segmentation fault on the code below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775429/why-am-i-getting-segmentation-fault-on-the-code-below)

The generate_nodes method is working after I made the changes according to the best answer I had. But now I'm having issues in generate_edges method.

graph node type:

```
#ifndef Graph_Structure
#define Graph_Structure

#include <stdbool.h>

struct Graph_Node{

    int id;
    char node_name[100];

    bool path;

    struct Graph_Node* next;
    struct Graph_Node* edge;
    struct Graph_Node* next_edge;

};  

typedef struct Graph_Node graph_node;


#endif
```

generate_edges method:

```
int generate_edges(graph_node **graph, const char *file_name){

    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n", file_name,
               strerror(errno));
       return 0;
    }

    char line[1024];

    size_t linenmr = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {

       linenmr++;
       // getting rid of the newline
       line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;

       if(strlen(line) > 12)
          continue; // resume reading, skip the line

       char *sep;
       long int dst = strtol(line, &sep, 0);

       sep++;

       long int src = strtol(sep, &sep, 0);

       //search for edge in graph

       //printf("dst: %ld ", dst); printf("src: %ld\n", src);

       add_edge(graph, src, dst);

    }

    return 1;

}
```

add_edge method:

```
void add_edge(graph_node **graph, int src, int dst){

    graph_node* temp = *graph;
    graph_node* temp2 = *graph;

    while(*graph != NULL){

        if((*graph)->id == src){ //search for edge source

            //printf("AQUI: %d\n", (*graph)->id);

            while(temp2 != NULL){ 

                if(temp2->id == dst){ //search for edge destination

                    //printf("AQUI 2: %d\n", temp->id);

                    (*graph)->next_edge = (*graph)->edge;
                    (*graph)->edge = temp2;
                    break;

                }

                temp2 = temp2->next;

            }

            temp2 = temp;
            break;

        }

        *graph = (*graph)->next;

    }   

    *graph = temp;

}
```

print_graph method:

```
void print_graph(graph_node* graph){

    if(graph == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{

        graph->path = true;

        printf("%d ", graph->id);
        puts(graph->node_name);             
        printf("\n");

        while(graph->edge != NULL){

            if(graph->edge->path == false)
                print_graph(graph->edge);

            graph->edge = graph->next_edge; 

        }

    }

}
```

what is happening is that when I try to print the graph I get stuck in an infinite loop inside "while" from method print_graph which doesn't make sense since I initialize all node's edges with null. It's like a node didn't have an edge with null value, but here is my insert code updated:

```
void insert_node(graph_node** node, graph_node data){

    graph_node* temp = (graph_node*)malloc(sizeof(graph_node));

    temp->id = data.id;

    strcpy(temp->node_name, data.node_name);
    temp->node_name[sizeof(temp->node_name) - 1] = 0;

    temp -> edge = NULL;
    temp -> next_edge = NULL;

    temp -> path = false;

    temp -> next = *node;
    *node = temp;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: you have a lot of problems in your code, and are missing a lot boundary checks. Which is why you're running into trouble.   You need to break down your issues into smaller chunks, so that you you can address them one at a time.  This is a bit of an artform, however even if you don't know it if you follow good programming hygiene, you'll end up with lesser issues. Paste your code somewhere so that we can compile it and help you along, as it stands your code is not really debuggable by anyone (including yourself)

Comment: Here is the link with all my code and there is an image with the graph I am trying to generate: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qhyq0v3g13gdldj/AABrj3XaUcHs4jSCWRoPtG-ya?dl=0

Comment: In the txt file lines with only numbers and commas are the edges. For example: 6,7,-1 is an edge from node 7 to 6 and 2,1,-1 is an edge from node 1 to 2. And these lines have allways less than 12 characters

Comment: @AhmedMasud I already posted the code!!

Comment: I'll have a look, sorry yesterday was just crazy.

Comment: @AhmedMasud ok man thank you!